# building a graph using two sets of nodes in R

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I am trying to build a graph in R using two sets of nodes with the same size. each list has some numbers in it representing node numbers. I want each node in the first list be connected to the corresponding node in the other list. For example list1[1] should be connected to list2[1] and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this would be to construct your graph with an edge list passed to the `graph.data.frame` function. The first column will be all the nodes in your first vector and the second will be all the nodes in your second vector:

```
list1 <- c("A", "B", "C")
list2 <- c("D", "E", "F")
library(igraph)
g <- graph.data.frame(cbind(list1, list2))
plot(g)
```

[image]